# Passing along Methods - Objective-C

Tags: iphone, ios, methods, selector

I'm fairly new to Objective-C, and it would be really helpful if someone could help me with the following task:

I have a class TheController that has a method DoTask. The goal of DoTask is to reach out to a MasterUtility (also a custom made class) and get Data, and then send it back when it is done (it uses a thread). Specifically, I want it to send it to dataReceiver in ReportsViewController. I think I need to use @selector or something like that. Here is some code:

```
@implementation ReportsViewController

-(void)doTask {
     MasterUtilities *mu = [[MasterUtilities alloc] init];
     [mu getDataAndSendTo:[WHAT GOES HERE]]
}

-(void)dataReceiver:(NSArray *)data {
    NSLog(@"data: %@",data);
}

@end
```

Here is MasterUtilities

```
    @implementation MasterUtilities

   - (void)getDataAndSendTo:[WHAT GOES HERE] {
        NSArray *data = [[NSArray init] alloc];
        ....getting data here....

        [WHAT GOES HERE? HOW DO I CALL THE METHOD (dataReceiver) IN ReportsViewController?]
     }

     @end
```

Can anyone fill in the areas that indicate "WHAT GOES HERE"? Thank you!!

---

---

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a block:

```
typedef void (^Callback)(NSArray*);

[somebody doSomethingAndPerform:^(NSArray *data) {
    // do whatever you want with the data
}];

- (void) doSomethingAndPerform: (Callback) callback
{
    NSArray *data = …;
    callback(data);
}
```

This is very flexible, but maybe too complex. If you want something simpler, you can always just pass the selector and target, just as you thought:

```
[somebody doSomethingAndCall:@selector(dataReceiver:) on:self];

- (void) doSomethingAndCall: (SEL) selector on: (id) target
{
    NSArray *data = …;
    [target performSelector:selector withObject:data];
}
```

Or you can use a protocol:

```
@protocol DataConsumer
- (void) handleData: (NSArray*) data;
@end

// this class has to implement DataConsumer
[somebody doSomethingAndNotify:self];

- (void) doSomethingAndNotify: (id <DataConsumer>) consumer
{
    NSArray *data = …;
    [consumer handleData:data];
}
```

This solution is a bit heawyweight, but the advantage is that the compiler catches some errors for you. There’s also more coupling, but it’s far from being a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the [Target-Action design pattern](http://macergun.blogspot.com/2009/06/target-action-design-pattern.html), which is widely used in Cocoa.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to reconsider how you approach this problem.

Rather than trying to get your `MasterUtilities` instance to send the data to your other method, why not have your `getData` method return the data from the method and then have your ReportsViewController pass the data to dataReciever: ?

Comment: He says he’s using a thread, so that he probably needs an asynchronous interface.